# Newtonian Mechanics - Differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, classical-mechanics

If we combine Newton's second law of motion i.e. $F=m\ddot{x}$ and Newton's law of gravity i.e., 
$$
F=G\frac{mM}{x^2},
$$
where $x$ is distance, we obtain the following equation:

$$\ddot{x}=MG\frac{1}{x^2}$$ My question is how do we solve this differential equation for $x$ ? I see no ordinary way of doing it. I have tried using Laplace transformation but apparently there exists no transformation for $\frac{1}{x^2}$ so I'm left with nothing to use.

Comment: Separation of variables since $M,G$ are constants.

Comment: I don't know that method, sadly enough.

Comment: it is already separated, just integrate both sides

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\ddot x=\frac{GM}{x^2}\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
\ddot x\dot x=\frac{GM\dot x}{x^2}\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
\frac{1}{2}(\dot x^2)^{\bf\dot{}} =-\left(\frac{GM}{x}\right)^{\!\bf\dot{}},
$$
which implies that
$$
\frac{1}{2}\dot x^2 =-\frac{GM}{x}+c,
$$
for some positive constant $c$.
Hence
$$
\dot x=\pm\sqrt{2c-\frac{2GM}{x}}.
$$

Comment: I agree with Copper.hat, just what I was looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  Set $p(x)=x'(t)$ so you'll have $x''(t)=p(t)p'(t)$ so $$x''=\frac{MC}{x^2}\to pp'=\frac{MC}{x^2}$$ and so $$\int pdp=\int \frac{MC}{x^2}dx$$

Answer (score 1):

First, there should be a minus in the front of your RHS.  But, moving on ...

When you have an acceleration dependent only on position, a typical technique is to transform the acceleration term like so:

$\displaystyle \frac{d}{dt}(\frac{dx}{dt})=\frac{dx}{dt}\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{dx}{dt})=\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{dx}{dt})^2$  So, dropping messy constants etc.

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{dx}{dt})^2 = -\frac{1}{x^2}$

or

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}(\frac{dx}{dt})^2 = \frac{1}{x} + E_0$

where $E_0$ is the initial energy of the system $v(0)^2/2-1/x(0)$.  This should be more tractable.

Answer (score 1):

You can trudge through the general solution (stipulating that $x=x(t)$) to

$$ x^{''} = f(x) $$

as

$$ \int [c_{1} +2 \int f(x) dx]^{-1/2} dx = c_{2} \pm t  $$

In your case (with $f(x)=MG/x^{2}$) the outer integral gets a bit messy, but still doable. Also, $c_1$ and $c_2$ are the integration constants you'll need to determine with your boundary conditions.

Hope this helps some.

Cheers,

Paul Safier

Answer (score -2):

(double dot χ)*(χ^2)= MG
But (double dot χ) equals the acceleration a, which equals ΔV/t.
This implies that;
(χ squered)= MGt/ΔV.
Hence
χ= Squere root(MGt/ΔV).
I hope this is helpful, as it is simple since it does not involve the trouble of integration constants.